# PHP get date between a date range and separate by week

Tags: php

How can I create a function that can return accurate start and end date within date range of given date that separate by week.

For example, a date range is given,

```
$startDate = '2022-08-05';
$endDate = '2022-08-16';
```

(2022-08-01 is the first day of the week but I want the data return start from the date that user given so do the end date)

So the output should be like this:

| 2022-08-05 to 2022-08-07 | 2022-08-08 to 2022-08-14 | 2022-08-15 to 2022-08-16 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data |
|  |  |  |

---

**My problem** is function I found cannot get data start from that date that user given but start from the first day of week and I have no idea how to modify it or create a new function. Any help is appreciate.

```
 function rangeWeek ($datestr) {
   date_default_timezone_set (date_default_timezone_get());
   $dt = strtotime ($datestr);
   return array (
     "start" => date ('N', $dt) == 1 ? date ('Y-m-d', $dt) : date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('last monday', $dt)),
     "end" => date('N', $dt) == 7 ? date ('Y-m-d', $dt) : date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('next sunday', $dt))
   );
 }
```

If I set the start date to '2022-08-05' then the output will be start from the first day of the week, how to let it start from '2022-08-05'?

```
print_r (rangeWeek('2022-08-05'));//output = Array ( [start] => 2022-08-01 [end] => 2022-08-07 )
```

Comment: Suggestion: The table to use the following layout: Column 1: Date Range, Column 2: Data (so the table only has two columns, and each week uses a new row).

Comment: Do you just need to get the right start date or the list of weeks?

Comment: The function you quoted in your question does not suit your need. Better write a new function with 2 parameters

Comment: This looks like a seemingly easy problem, but is probably more difficult to solve. What about a series of weeks that run over a new year, for instance? I would look into using week numbers: `date('W', <timestamp>)`. Walk all the years and weeks as needed, and check for the edge cases where the week contains either the start or end date.

Comment: PHP has [a whole suite of classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) to help with the representation of date/time information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate from start to end date and check the week for each day. So you know the week begin and end.

#### Example

```
function rangeWeek(string $start, string $end): array
{
    $start     = new DateTime($start);
    $end       = new DateTime($end);
    $interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $period    = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
    $weeks     = [];
    $oldWeek   = null;
    $weekStart = null;
    foreach ($period as $date) {
        $week = $date->format('W');
        if ($week !== $oldWeek) {
            if (null === $weekStart) {
                $oldWeek   = $week;
                $weekStart = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            } else {
                $weeks[]   = ['start' => $weekStart, 'end' => $date->format('Y-m-d'), 'week' => $week];
                $weekStart = null;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    $weeks[] = ['start' => $weekStart, 'end' => $end->format('Y-m-d'), 'week' => $week];

    return $weeks;
}

$startDate = '2022-08-05';
$endDate   = '2022-08-20';
$weeks     = rangeWeek($startDate, $endDate);
print_r($weeks);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2022-08-05
            [end] => 2022-08-08
            [week] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2022-08-09
            [end] => 2022-08-15
            [week] => 33
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2022-08-16
            [end] => 2022-08-20
            [week] => 33
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, the start date work perfectly but if I set the end date to '2022-08-20' then it can only return until the week before it but not the week of '2022-08-20' which is until '2022-08-15' only.

Comment: No problem. You can add the rest after the loop. See updated answer.

Comment: I have a problem when I set the date from this Monday to next Monday,it will return 8 days in a week. I tried add ```$end->modify('-1');``` but still cant fix it.

Comment: For example, if the startDate is '2022-08-08' and the endDate is '2022-08-16', the first week will return 8 days and the [start] of second week will disappear.

Comment: This code works on basis of changed weeknumber. In your case it must be rewritten respecting the weekday.